# Notice: Undefined variable: ordenarpor

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error when trying sorting results with session from a MSSQL database. I think I already defined the variable, but I still getting the variable is not defined. This is the code:

```
                    session_start();
                $ordernarpor = 'id';
                if(isset($_GET['orderna']))
                {
                    $ordernarpor = $_GET['orderna'];
                    $_SESSION['orderna'] = $ordernarpor;
                }
                else if(isset($_SESSION['orderna']))
                {
                    $ordernarpor = $_SESSION['orderna'];
                }
                $ordenar = '';
                if ($ordenarpor== 'id')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY id";
                }
                elseif ($ordenarpor== 'nome')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY nome";
                }
                elseif ($ordenarpor== 'idade')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY idade";
                }
                elseif($ordenarpor== 'peso')
                {
                    $ordenar .= " ORDER BY peso";
                }   
                $nomeServidor = "fsadxas-DEMO"; 
                $opcao = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "xzcsa",  "Database" => "demo");
                $conexao = sqlsrv_connect($nomeServidor, $opcao);
                if( $conexao ) {
                $sql="SELECT * FROM cliente" . $ordenar;
                $aResult=sqlsrv_query($conexao, $sql);
                while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($aResult))
                { 
                    $id = $rows['id'];
                    $nome = $rows['nome'];
                    $idade = $rows['idade'];
                    $peso = $rows['peso'];
```

Thanks if anyone can help me with this problem

Comment: This is not a code review service. Read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully.

Comment: Replace $ordenarpor to $ordernarpor

Answer (score 2):

Replace those code

```
            $ordernarpor = 'id';
            if(isset($_GET['orderna']))
            {
                $ordernarpor = $_GET['orderna'];
                $_SESSION['orderna'] = $ordernarpor;
            }
            else if(isset($_SESSION['orderna']))
            {
                $ordernarpor = $_SESSION['orderna'];
            }
            $ordenar = '';
            if ($ordernarpor == 'id')
            {
                $ordenar .= " ORDER BY id";
            }
            elseif ($ordernarpor== 'nome')
            {
                $ordenar .= " ORDER BY nome";
            }
            elseif ($ordernarpor== 'idade')
            {
                $ordenar .= " ORDER BY idade";
            }
            elseif($ordernarpor== 'peso')
            {
                $ordenar .= " ORDER BY peso";
            }
```

You used ordernarpor and ordenarpor. But you only defined ordernarpor.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly did you replaced?

Comment: You used ordernarpor and ordenarpor. But you only defined ordernarpor.
If you want 2 variable defined thus 2 variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized the variable as $ordernarpor but using the same variable with $ordenarpor. this is just a typo mistake nothing else.